# C# - why is it not possible to access 'this' in a field initializer?

Tags: c#, constructor

Why does this produce a compiler error:

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar Baz = new Bar(this);
}
```

But this does not:

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar Baz;

    public Foo()
    {
        this.Baz = new Bar(this);
    }
}
```

Conceptually the two are equivalent, are they not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, they're not quite equivalent... the variable initializer executes *before* any base class constructors are run. The body of the constructor executes *after* base class constructors are run. (This is different from Java, where variable initializers execute after base class constructors but before the constructor body.)

Therefore it's safer to access `this` within the constructor body: you can be sure that the object is initialized at least in respect to its base class (and upwards).

I *believe* that's the reasoning, anyway...

Comment: If you could call an instance method from a field initializer, you could call a member method of the base type, and the body of that method would run before the object was initialized, defeating a very basic language contract (that the constructor runs when the object is created).

Comment: Well, you can sort of do that anyway - you can call a virtual member implemented in a derived class before that derived class's constructor body has run. That's generally frowned upon though.

Comment: Ahh, so the basic idea is to make it so, that a method of a class will never be called before the constructor has at least started to execute. Makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that is the reasoning. Some notes on related matters: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx  and http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is not logical to access the class that is not initialized yet.
If you would be able to access this it would mean that Bar is already initialized that is not true till the constructor is not finished.

Comment: And it is supposed to be "initialized" in the middle of the constructor?

Comment: No, but at least in the middle of the constructor you can rely upon two things. (1) all the field initializers on both derived and base classes are fully executed and (2) all base class constructors are fully executed. That gives you a lot more confidence when using "this" in a constructor body. Were we to allow you to use "this" in a field initializer, neither of those two things would be true, which would increase the risk of error.

Answer (score 1):

Because at that point (in you first example) the object has not been constructed yet. In the constructor it is already.

In the constructor body you have an option to do extra initialization but only if you wish - change field values, call other methods, whatever. But this is optional. So you may count on a *technically* constructed object here, while it may not be really constructed according to your application logic. But then it is you who has to watch out, not compiler any more.

Comment: What do you mean by "has not been constructed yet"?

Answer (score 1):

Because the class you're referencing hasn't been initialised yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar Baz = new Bar(this);
}
```

"this" represents the object of a "Foo" class. And you don't have the class object initiated at this point.

Suppose, "Bar" constructor don't need the "Foo" instance to initiate (or call its constructor) like Bar("hello!") then the above statement could be compiled as:

```
class Foo
{
    public static Bar Baz = new Bar("Hello!");
}
```

Which can be accessed through:

```
Foo.Baz.something();
```

A class can initiate an instance which should be marked with "static" keyword and don't need the class instance to initiate.

Answer (score 0):

One point other answers haven't mentioned is that the rules for field initialization are different in C# and vb.net.  In C#, if Foo:Bar:Boz:Object, constructors and field initializers are run in the sequence:

1. Foo initializers

   Bar initializer

   Boz initializer

   Boz constructor

   Bar constructor

   Foo constructor

In vb.net, the sequence is:

1. Boz intializers

   Boz constructor

   Bar initializers

   Bar constructor

   Foo initializers

   Foo constructor

One advantage of the vb.net approach is that it is possible for field initializers to make use of the object under construction, since everything in the object and its base types will have been initialized up to the point of the initialization.  There are a few cases where the C# approach may be helpful, but I would consider them relatively few and far between, given that the the supposed advantage can only apply in cases where a field which is needed by a virtual method can be initialized without directly or indirectly needing any of the constructor's parameters; those cases could nearly always be handled by having the virtual method check whether the object was initialized yet and initialize it if not (it would have all the information which would have been available to "early" field initializers).

Frankly, I think both vb.net and c# would be improved if there were a reasonable means for field initializers to access constructor parameters.  In vb, since field initializers run after the base is constructed, one could have a base-class constructor store its parameter to a field, and have a derived-class constructor use that field to initialize others.  If, for example, `MyArray[]` will always refer to the same array throughout the lifetime of an object, saying:

```
' ConstructorParam is defined and set in base class ParamInitClass(Of Integer)
  ReadOnly MyArray(ConstructorParam) As Integer
...
Sub New(ArraySize As Integer)
  MyBase.New(ArraySize)
End Sub
```

seems clearer than

```
  ReadOnly MyArray() As Integer

Sub New(ArraySize As Integer)
  Redim MyArray(ArraySize)
End Sub
```

Note that in C#, the only way one could attempt to do such things would be via `threadstatic` variables, but such techniques would be rather dodgy at best.